# PHP how to prevent override of get type

Tags: jquery, ajax

The wording of the question is a bit weird, but that's because I am not quite sure how to put it in words. My problem is as follows. I am making a .get request to my php file through JS using ajax.

I have two methods one that is responsible for fetching meaning, and thus I say:

```
$.get("babynames.php",
    {
       type: "meaning",
       name: nested
    },
    function (data) {
        //alert("Data loaded " + data);
        $("#meaning").innerHTML = data;
    });
```

And another responsible for ranking (work in progress), which looks like so:

```
$.get("babynames.php",
        {
            type: "rank",
            name: name,
            gender: gender
        },
        function(data){
        //$("#grapharea").append(data);
            document.getElementById("graph").innerHTML = data;
    });
```

The expected output in my index.php will look as so:

```
The name <name here> means: 
__________________________________________________

<name meaning> 

Popularity:

<Ranking goes here>
```

However, both name and ranking go below popularity as it seems as though the type later on gets set to "rank". The way I call my two JS functions is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    $("#resultsarea").show(); // un-hides the display area with all the info
    nested = document.getElementById("allnames");
    nested = nested.options[nested.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("nested").innerHTML = nested;
    e.preventDefault();
    meaning();
    rank();
});
```

Where have I gone awry?

Comment: Looking around, it seems setting an async flag would help(?) what exactly is the syntax for setting it?

Comment: Async is true by default, but what I don't understand is why you're making 2 separate requests, also mixing normal JS with jQuery (while perfectly allowed but its making a mess of things)

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and DOM syntax. `$("#meaning").innerHTML = data;` should be `$("#meaning").html(data)`.

Comment: ^ that is what I meant..

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `nested.selectedIndex`. `nested.value` will return the value of the selected option.

Comment: group project, so many hands in the kitchen. Issue is still present, I am uncertain though as to why type is set to rank and seems to avoid meaning. Won't it be like, call meaning --> request php response --> getResponse and set .html; then same thing for rank?

Comment: Ya know, it is kinda strange, but all I did to fix it was set a variable in my php to get meaning, then do strpos on it and it magically worked...cuz doing strpos with _GET directly didn't. At least, that's all it seemed to do in my eyes

Comment: Are you leaving this question unattended? No upvotes, no marks, nothing? Have the curtousy to upvote when something is usefull or atleast leave a comment when something didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Old question mate, I think I figured it out, but it was a long time ago. Also, considering how stack has treated me before for asking beginner questions; be glad I am not wealthy enough to purchase the company behind this website. First order of business would be to shut it down for a month.

Comment: also seems you are bitter about me not upvoting you, but your answer seems to be what I used in the end; can't recall if it was what I did immediately. As you can tell, November, 2016 was a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing two styles of scripting doesn't usually go well together as Barmar pointed out already.

```
<?php
  #babynames.php

  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    // fetch meaning
    // fetch rank

        $response = [
            'rank' => $rank,
            'meaning' => $meaning
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);
  }

?>
```

And for the client:

```
$(function(){
  $("#search").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#allnames").change(function(e){
    alert($("#allnames option:selected").text()); // use the one that works
    alert($("#allnames option:selected").val()); // I dont have your html code.

    var name = $("#allnames option:selected").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'babynames.php'
      data: {name:name},
      success: function(json){
        alert("Look at our PHP response.. " + json);
        var o = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        alert(o.rank);
        alert(o.meaning);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Truth be told, I don't know if this code contains syntax errors but it needs a little bit of work anyways.

The idea is to just use 1 request for each change made to the dropdown list. You have a name, submit it to PHP, fetch the ranking and meaning and return both in 1 response.

Look and learn from this code, this is how you should handle events.